# how to use CreateEvent with not null LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES parameter

Tags: c++, winapi, events

i have a process-1 that try to open event using:

```
LPCWSTR a = L"ShellReadyEvent";
HANDLE hEvent = OpenEvent ( EVENT_ALL_ACCESS , 0, a );
```

i am trying to make a process in the background that will change the the access privilege 
of the even a.

i am trying to use create event under process-2 using :

```
HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent ( 0 , 1 , 1 , a );
```

i want to replace the lpEventAttributes (first parameter) to something that will block the first process but no luck, and ideas?

Comment: You want to prevent process-1 from opening the event?

Comment: yes i want that when he tries to run the OpenEvent he will fail

Comment: Security attributes control access rights of users. So run process 2 as a different user, and restrict access to just that user. Might be easier to change process 1 though.

Comment: cannot change process 1, how do you suggest doing it?

Comment: Like David said, run process-1 as a different user (you don't have to change process-1 itself, just how it is run), then have process-2 deny access to that user when creating the event.

Comment: I'm sure the author of process 1 will be happy to help

Answer (score 3):

Run process-1 using a different user account than process-2, then process-2 can create a [`SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379561.aspx) that denies access to that user, and pass it to [`CreateEvent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396.aspx) using a [`SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379560.aspx) structure.

To actually create the `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR`, you can either:

1. Use [`InitializeAcl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378853.aspx) and [`AddAccessDeniedAce()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374962.aspx) to create an ACL that denies the `SID` of process-1's user account.  Use [`LookupAccountName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379159.aspx) or related function to get the user's SID.  Use [`InitializeSecurityDescriptor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378863.aspx) and [`SetSecurityDescriptorDacl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379583.aspx) to create a [`SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379561.aspx) that uses the ACL.
2. Use [`ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376401.aspx) to create the `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` from a string that describes everything you want in the ACL.  See this example: [Creating a DACL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717798.aspx).